# Cannot get my cell to update with user edited info in diffable tableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, diffabledatasource

I am trying to create a Diffable tableView who's cells can be updated (info and layout) by the user (ie- hiding or showing a label or image that holds an optional property) in a separate editing tableview attached to the cell through a segue. I started by adding a backingStore property who's values are a custom `ListItem` class. The class is hashable with a UUID() as one of the properties.

```
class ListDrillDownTableViewController: UITableViewController {
fileprivate var dataSource: ListDrillDownDataSource!
fileprivate var currentSnapshot: ListDrillDownSnaphot?

var list: List = List(name: "Test List", listStyle: .preSetStyle[0], listItems: [], users: [])
var backingStore = [UUID: ListItem]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.dataSource = createDataSource()
    updateUI(animated: false) 
}
```

Then I created a method to create the dataSource giving the cell provider the UUID to look up the listItem. I also updated the UI with the initial snapshot populating the UUIDs and the backingStore.

```
 fileprivate func createDataSource() -> ListDrillDownDataSource {
    let dataSource = ListDrillDownDataSource(tableView: tableView) { (tableView, indexPath, uuid) -> UITableViewCell? in
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ListItemCell", for: indexPath) as! ListItemCell
        guard let listItem = self.backingStore[uuid] else { return cell }
        cell.titleLabel.text = listItem.title
        
        if let cost = listItem.cost {
            cell.costLabel.isHidden = false
            cell.costLabel.text = (listItem.costString(cost: cost))
        } else {
            cell.costLabel.isHidden = true
        }
        if listItem.note == "" {
            cell.noteIcon.isHidden = true
        } else {
            cell.noteIcon.isHidden = false
        }
        return cell
    }
    self.tableView.dataSource = dataSource
    return dataSource
}

func updateUI(animated: Bool = true) {
    var snapshot = ListDrillDownSnaphot()
    snapshot.appendSections(["main"])
    let uuids = self.list.listItems.map { _ in UUID() }
    snapshot.appendItems(uuids)
    for (uuid, listItem) in zip(uuids, list.listItems) {
        self.backingStore[uuid] = listItem
    }
    self.dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: animated)
}
```

Finally, when the user taps a cell, makes there edits and taps done the view unwinds back to this controller and I attempt to update the dataSource in the unwind method. As it stands the app will create the first new cell but when a second is attempted it reloads the first row twice and as I keep adding it doubles the existing rows. I'm guessing because I'm appending the whole list over and over? I can't figure out how to access JUST the appended uuid.

When I tap into an existing cell and edit the info it works, but if I go in again to the row and come out the cell goes back to it's original state. If I keep trying it bounces back and forth between the original state and the updated, almost like it is bouncing back and forth between snapshots? I feel like I'm missing something obvious but I can't seem to figure it out. Any thoughts?

```
   @IBAction func unwindToListDrillDownTableView(_ unwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    guard unwindSegue.identifier == "DoneAddEditListItemUnwind" else { return }
    let sourceViewController = unwindSegue.source as! ListItemDetailTableViewController
   self.list.listStyle?.categories = sourceViewController.currentCategories
    if let listItem = sourceViewController.listItem {
        if let indexOfExistingListItem = list.listItems.firstIndex(of: listItem) {
        // If existing, update the ListItem and then the view.
            list.listItems[indexOfExistingListItem] = listItem
            let uuid = self.dataSource.itemIdentifier(for: IndexPath(row: indexOfExistingListItem, section: 0))
            let uuids = self.list.listItems.map { _ in UUID() }
            var snapshot = self.dataSource.snapshot()
            snapshot.reloadItems([uuid!])
            for (uuid, listItem) in zip(uuids, list.listItems) {
                self.backingStore[uuid] = listItem
            }
            self.dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: true)
        } else {
            list.listItems.append(listItem)
            if self.backingStore.keys.isEmpty {
                updateUI()
            } else {
                var snapshot = self.dataSource.snapshot()
                let uuids = self.list.listItems.map { _ in UUID() }
                snapshot.reloadSections(["main"])
                snapshot.appendItems(uuids)
                for (uuid, listItem) in zip(uuids, list.listItems) {
                    self.backingStore[uuid] = listItem
                }
                self.dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have both `list` and `backingstore`? Your data source should be able to operate with just your List.  Also it would seem to be a containment violation to access `list.listItems` - you should create functions in `List` that perform searches and retrieve existing items. What is `ListItem`? Is it a struct or a class?

Comment: ListItem is set up as a class which is the items a user adds to the list. I have them stored as an array in the list as the user will be able to create multiple lists and view them all on a different view. List is only instantiated because I haven't built the "list of lists" screen yet which will ultimately pass the chosen list into this screen. I had read and got comments from different related questions that a backing store is needed for user updated cells as the Diffable dataSource can't pull out and update the changes on it's own?

Comment: So you're saying it is best to create functions in 'List' that return the properties I need and then call those functions instead of trying to access the properties directly? (I probably don't need to fill you in that I'm very new to this lol).